# Who vs. whom in complex sentences

Tags: whom, whoever-vs-whomever

I know that *who* is used when asking about a subject (*Who is at the door?*) and *whom* is used when asking about an object (*By whom was the door opened?*). How do you determine which one to use when the object becomes the subject of another clause?

For example, take the sentence:

> I gave the prize to ____ deserved it most.

Would it be *whomever* because it's the object of "gave," or would it be *whoever* because it's the subject of "deserved"? Is their a hard-and-fast rule to rely on in situations like this?

Comment: In those cases, never use _whom_ unless you've left it as the object of a preposition that comes right before (e.g, _by whom, for whom, with whom_). That situation requires _whom_; no other situation requires it, and that situation can be avoided by stranding the preposition (_Who was the door opened by?_). Executive Summary: Don't use _whom_.

Comment: @JohnLawler You caveat is well made! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Whoever" would be correct.  The blank in your sentence is *not* the object of "gave".  The entire clause "___ deserved it most" is the object of "gave", which in turn means you'll use "whoever", which is the subject of "deserved".

The rule here is exactly like what you said:  who = subject, whom = object.  The trick in this case is understanding the clauses in this sentence.

Comment: No, that's no longer the rule. Read Professor Lawler's comment (and see many other posts here on who / whom).

Comment: Yes, that is the rule. Still. I.e, the rule is that _whoever_ is correct as the subject of _deserved it most_, and _whomever_ is not correct. You do hafta use the _-other_ construct to make it nonspecific indefinite, but nothing makes the subject of a tensed verb accusative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think most people agree that this is still the rule in formal English, which is what most people asking this question are after.

Comment: The answerer states 'the rule' re 'who' and 'whom', not 'whoever' and 'whomever'. 'The rule here is exactly like what you said: who = subject, whom = object.' But I'd consider 'Whom were you hit by?'  to be definitely on the way out nowadays.