# Whom vs. who; which is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, whom, pied-piping

Who/whom question:

"I have no idea whom he was speaking about."

The subject of the phrase, "was speaking about" is, he, hence "whom" is correct (flip it around, "about whom he was speaking').

But it doesn't *sound* correct.

Comment: This question comes closest (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202650/who-vs-whom-in-complex-sentences) but fails to give a clear answer.

Comment: Do you speak about he or about him? About they or about them?

Answer (score -2):

It does sound wrong imho. So why not flip it around as you suggested "about whom he was speaking", or better still, "of whom he was speaking". You get to avoid a trailing preposition hehe...

Comment: That's not a trailing preposition, and so there's no reason to avoid it.